# How to avoid Spring Roo GWT support?

Tags: java, gwt, spring-roo

I am experimenting with Spring Roo in a new GWT application. The Spring Roo GWT support is some way off ready for real use just yet, so I want to build the GWT stuff by hand using as much of the GWT 2.1 MVP stuff as possible. The problem I have is that Spring Roo "notices" my MVP-related classes and generates a whole lot of extra (broken) stuff for my entities.

How can I get Spring Roo to ignore the GWT side of my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed my gwt.scaffold package to gwt.shell and gwt.request to gwt.req and Spring Roo is leaving my stuff alone.

Answer (score 3):

> "I want to build the GWT stuff by hand using as much of the GWT 2.1 MVP stuff as possible"

If you're building GWT by hand, it sounds like you're interested in using Spring Roo to generate your data model code — but don't want (or need) any of Spring Roo's web controller code. If that's the case then you can separate your project into two modules:

- A module containing model and persistence code that is created by Spring Roo
- A GWT web application that you create by hand.

Make the first (Roo) module a dependency of the second (GWT) module. Basically you're using Roo to create a JAR library that's used by your web application. As long as you don't run the `controller` command the Roo won't add any web application code to your module.

Comment: Ah I was hoping to avoid having to do that. But it will work if nothing else does, I suppose.